# Why does this throw a SIGSEGV? (Heap-allocated std::array)

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, heap-memory

I'm looking to build a 1D `std::array` of structs, each of whose size is 16 bytes. The 1D array is a flattening of a class representing a 3D array (basically an `std::array` wrapper that has some 3D specific operators and other fluff). My first attempt is an array of size 256 x 256 x 32, so roughly 35MB, which throws a SIGSEGV error.

A simplified example of everything looks like this:

**Structs.cpp**

```
struct Coord {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    Coord() { }
    Coord(int x_, int y_, int z_) { x = x_; y = y_; z = z_; }
}

int TR (int arg) { 
    // ... Some transformation 
} 

struct MyStruct {
    Coord position;
    int terrain;

    MyStruct() { }
    MyStruct(int x_, int y_, int z_, int terrain_) { 
        terrain = terrain_;
        position = Coord(TR(x_), TR(y_), TR(z_));
    }
}
```

**ArrayWrapper.hpp**

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, int HSIZE, int VSIZE> struct ArrayWrapper { 
    private:
        std::array<T, HSIZE*HSIZE*VSIZE> narray;

    public:
        void set(T obj, int x, int y, int z) {
            narray[x + z*HSIZE + y*HSIZE*HSIZE] = obj;
        }

        T& operator() (int x, int y, int z) {
            return narray.at(x + z*HSIZE + y*HSIZE*HSIZE);
        }
```

**CoordinateMap.cpp**

```
#include "ArrayWrapper.hpp"
#include "Structs.cpp"

const int HSIZE = 256;
const int VSIZE = 32;

class CMap {
    private: 
        ArrayWrapper<MyStruct, HSIZE, VSIZE>* coords_ = new ArrayWrapper<MyStruct, HSIZE, VSIZE>;
        ArrayWrapper<MyStruct, HSIZE, VSIZE> coords = *coords_;

    public:
        // ... Getter, setter, and a bunch of other methods, 
        ~CMap() { delete coords; }
}
```

If I anywhere try to say `CMap something;` I get a SIGSEGV. I know that the stack is relatively small, so I'm attempting to allocate this structure on the heap by using `new`. Many people (on this site and others) say "Finding a large range of *contiguous* memory is difficult, even if it's on the heap," but don't give an indication of what a reasonable expectation of the size of contiguous memory is. I would think 32MB in a modern-day computer is doable.

What might be throwing a Seg. fault here?

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to catch the crash, and see when and where in your code it happens?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have, yes—that is how I know that the line `CMap something;` is what causes the SIGSEGV, but `gdb` doesn't give any further information. (Albeit, I'm using the class via the Catch2 [unit testing framework] interface, so maybe that is cluttering things up.)

Comment: The thing is, if `new` fails it should throw an exception, not a segmentation fault. Segmentation faults typically comes when you try to write to memory your process doesn't own.

Comment: The shown code in this question fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone here can determine the problem. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah. I wonder if it is indeed Catch2 that's causing the error, and not the code itself. The code itself seems relatively straightforward, which is why I'm surprised I'm getting the error in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayWrapper<MyStruct, HSIZE, VSIZE> coords = *coords_;
```

Should be...

```
ArrayWrapper<MyStruct, HSIZE, VSIZE>& coords = *coords_;
```

... which makes sense. The 1st line is making a copy of `coords_`' reference, which, in this case, defeats the purpose of using `new`, since that copy is put on the stack.